# Token based Authentication mechanism for REST API

Tags: http, rest, authentication

I have a network device (running c++) in my local network which runs a http(s) server and provides a Restlike webservice interface to provide an API to control the device.
Now my question is, how can i authorize the user (an android smartphone in the same network) for using the Rest api?
The scenario is as like this: The user on the smartphone has to enter a PIN cod (4-digits) in order to get access to the api from then on it should be possible to call all the other REST API methods.

My idea: 
1) the pin code will be send to the device via http(s) POST body, the device checks if it is okay.
2) if the PIN is right, the device will generate a token, which has to be used on every future request.

so my questions are:
* how should i generate such a token (what algorithm) on the device using c++
* how should the token be transmitted on every request? As a query parameter? Or in the POST body? or in the Header?

EDIT: i also read about [http basic authentication](http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/). could this be used in my setup too?
kind regards

Answer (score 0):

When submitting tokens using headers or POST body, never in the Url as part of query string.

See OWASP page for REST: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Authentication_and_Session_Management

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: store it in the header, the code could use a hash algorithm to generate the token and your idea is right in the first point, but make sure those tokens have finite lifetime.